# How to process the files in NodeJS sent from client FormData?

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, file-upload

I use HTML5 FormData to upload files from the client to Node Server. In the node server, I have included `multiparty` module to process the uploaded, but not sure of how it works.

server.js:

```
var parms = urlLib.parse(req.url, true);
var form = new multiparty.Form();
form.parse(req, function (err,fields,files) {
   console.log(fields, files);
});
```

I want to know how to write the code for processing the uploaded file. I have tried using `fs.readFile` and `fs.createReadStream`, but node threw an error "file path must be of type `String`" but the uploaded files are blob object. So, how do i proceed further?